# how can I find with mongodb a collection with two different parameters

Tags: mongodb

```
{
  "A": 123
  "B": "test",
  "C": true
}
```

```
db.col.find({A: 'afg', B: 'test'})
```

How can I find with Mongodb a collection with two different parameters

it should try first to search `A:` then it will try search `B:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [or operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/).

```
db.col.find({ 
  $or: [
    { A: 'afg' }, 
    { B: 'test' }
  ]
});
```